# Passing variables from one function to another

Tags: php, function, variables

I have set a variable in one function and I am trying to use it in another. People seem to be advising against using globals for functions.

This code is in my first variable

```
 if($this->CheckAndSetupContractHitman($player_data_tab,$player_defence_data_tab)) $winner_exp = $winner_exp + floor($winner_exp*0.4);

 if($this->CheckAndSetupContractHitman($player_data_tab,$player_defence_data_tab)) $bonus_exp = floor($winner_exp*0.2857);
```

It is the variable `$bonus_exp` that I am trying to pass on to another function. Should I add return `$bonus_exp;` at the end of the first variable and then add `$bonus_exp` as an argument to the second variable like so?

```
function CheckAndSetupContractHitman($player_data_tab,$player_defence_data_tab,$bonus_exp)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking properly, but as a general rule, if you have `function example1()` and you call it from `function example2()` anything in `example1()` you want to use in `example2()` pass it as an argument in `example2()`. Anything in `example2()` you want to use in `example1()`, return it from inside `example2()` There are exceptions of course, like passing by reference, but that's the general rule of thumb.

Comment: You also have globals, but, as you said, those aren't recommended. I'm not sure I ever knew the reasons for this, but I think it's to keep you from accidentally overwriting it somewhere. It's also better form to pass as a param and return.

Comment: @Chipster [because they are evil global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158418/2123530) but [not as evil as that in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557799/2123530). *nota: two links in here*

Comment: First, understand the difference between "variable" and "function." And then, since you seem to be inside an object, you'll want to understand what a "property" and "method" are. The answer likely lies in using class properties.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for 
[Passing by Reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

I think you should think out another solution for your problem, but *Passing by Reference* is better then using globals.

Answer (score 0):

I would do as you suggest, using a `return` and passing the parameter.  With one exception:  Make it equal nothing (empty) -- That way .. The function doesn't *technically* need it as an input, and you can simply include it, or not, at your discretion.

```
function CheckAndSetupContractHitman($player_data_tab,$player_defence_data_tab,$bonus_exp = ''){
    if ($bonus_exp != ''){
        // Do something
    }
// ....
return bonus_exp;
}
```

Set up this way --  If you call the function **without** `$bonus_exp` IE

```
CheckAndSetupContractHitman($player_data_tab,$player_defence_data_tab);
```

`$bonus_exp` will be set to `''`

But if you have it set and **pass** it in ... It will be set to whatever you passed.  IE

```
$bonus_exp = 50;
CheckAndSetupContractHitman($player_data_tab,$player_defence_data_tab,$bonus_exp);
```

`$bonus_exp` would be passed as `50` into the function.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help. Am I right in thinking that return causes the function to end? So I will have to use return $bonus_exp; at the end of my first function to get it out of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly there are 2 ways to get some variables from a function.

Firstly as you said pass by reference.

Other one is a return value. It is possible to get more than 1 value with return, when  you return an array like:

```
if(expression){
    return ["exp" => $exp, "bonus",$bonus];
} else {
   return false;
}
```

So you can use like

```
if($array = topFunction($param1,$param2)){
    $exp = $array["exp"];
    $bonus = $array["bonus"];
}
```

I prefer second one. You should not execute 2 times same function.

Comment: There are now [more elegant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) ways than returning array